# Javafx rectangles in quadtree won't dissappear/be created - using mouseevents

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, 2d, quadtree

I've made a program that creates a simple visual quadtree - basically starts with a grid of 4 rectangles which can each be divided into a smaller version of a grid containing 4 smaller rectangles. **PROBLEM:** Sometimes though, one of the original 4 squares refuses to divide, while the others continue working. The issue only occurs after I've tried right-clicking several times when the grid is already combined to one base square that cannot be combined any further.

I've attached a `.setOnMouseClicked()` handler on each square that calls my `divide()` method on left-click and `combine()` on right-click. Furthermore the handler method are set to check if the square that's been clicked belongs to a grid of squares before it tries to call the combine method, and this is where I struggle to understand what goes wrong.

My theories so far:

- Perhaps the issue relates to how javafx handles visual objects, but I hoped that using `.getChildren().remove(Object o);` was the right way to remove something from the scene. It seems to work most of the time though.
- Maybe the way I'm changing what's displayed and not isn't really thread safe, and that using an eventHandler interrupts the object removal - but the problem occurs when I'm clicking slowly as well as rapidly.

The class hierarchy consists of one abstract `Cell` class that can either be a `Grid` or a `Square`. Excuse me for dropping a lot of code here, but javafx debugging confuses me a lot some times, so honestly I got no idea which part of the code is responsible, thus I pasted the entire thing.

**Cell.java:**

```
public abstract class Cell {
    int x, y, w, h, id; //id is a reference the index in a grid this cell belongs to - it's used when a square replaces itself with a grid
    Pane pane;
    Cell parent;

    public Cell(Pane pane, Cell parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, int id) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.id = id;
        this.pane = pane;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void divide(){}
    public abstract void remove();
}
```

**Grid.java**

```
public class Grid extends Cell {
    Cell[] grid = new Cell[4];

    public Grid(Pane pane, Cell parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, int id) {
        //The constructor works as it should, just some unnecessary maths to avoid confusion over rounding
        super(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);
        int ver = x + w/2;
        int hor = y + h/2;
        grid[0] = new Square(pane, this, x, y, w/2, h/2, 0);
        grid[1] = new Square(pane, this, ver+1, y, x+w-1-ver, h/2, 1);
        grid[2] = new Square(pane, this, x, hor+1, w/2, y+h-1-hor, 2);
        grid[3] = new Square(pane, this, ver+1, hor+1, x+w-1-ver, y+h-1-hor, 3);
    }

    public void combine(){
        remove();
        parent = new Square(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);
    }

    public void remove(){
        for(Cell c : grid){
            c.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

**Square.java:**

```
public class Square extends Cell {
    Rectangle rect;

    public Square(Pane pane, Cell parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, int id) {
        super(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);
        rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
        rect.setFill(Color.RED);
        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        rect.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY))
                divide();
            else if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY) && parent != null && parent.getClass().equals(Grid.class))
                ((Grid)parent).combine();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void divide(){
        if(w > 3 && h > 3){
            remove();
            if(parent != null && parent.getClass().equals(Grid.class))
                ((Grid)parent).grid[id] = new Grid(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);
            else
                parent = new Grid(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);
        }
    }

    public void remove(){
        pane.getChildren().remove(rect);
    }
}
```

In the main file, the `parent` is initialized as `null` for the base `Cell` to signalize that it cannot be divided from the mouse handler:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, null, null)));
    cell = new Square(pane, null, 50, 50, 700, 700, 0);
    cell.divide(); //cell is a Cell type instance variable
    primaryStage.setTitle("SquareSception");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 800, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The outlined squares refuses to divide despite many left-clicks
[image: The outlined squares refuses to divide despite many left-clicks]
The top right square refuses to divide, the others would
[image: The top right square refuses to divide, the others would]

Comment: I should also mention than in the pictures I was holding my mouse in the top right area as I was right-clicking, seems like a correlation between where I right-click and were left-clicking stops responding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should change the type of `parent` to `Grid`.This avoids the unnecessary type checking. (Every parent is a `Grid` after all.)

The real issue however is, that you never properly update the parent grid in `Grid.combine`. You need to do this update in order for the `remove` method to properly find all child squares:

```
public void combine(){
    remove();
    Square newParent = new Square(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.setChild(newParent);
    }
}

public void setChild(Cell newChild) {
    grid[newChild.id] = newChild;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is dead on, but I need the type checking as I set the parent to be a new Square during combine().. I could've removed it all if I didn't have to check for the base case where there is no parent, or in other words I have to combine the outer grid to be just one square... Setting the parents array at index id doesn't make sense then.

Comment: @Chexxor However a `Square` does not truely serve as parent. `parent = new Square(pane, parent, x, y, w, h, id);` won't accomplish anything but setting the field. Instead of really using it as parent of the current node, you're replacing the current node with a square in this case of the `combine` method. Also note that after removing the grid you won't have any way to interact with it.

Comment: Nevermind, just saw a mistake in my adaption of your code :O It should work indeed

Comment: But shouldn't parent and parent.parent.grid[id] serve as a reference to the exact same memory location? Such that replacing the contents of parent would also replace the content of the parent.parent.grid[id], I mean like in C++ where two pointer variables / references can point to the same content, which in turn can be replaced?

Comment: @Chexxor Indeed pointers and java (non-primitive) variables are similar, but you'll always have one "root" which does not have a parent. But: when do you use a `Square` stored as `parent` except for checking the type? So if you do not treat a parent that is a `Square` different to a parent that is `null`, why bother and store a `Square` in the `parent` field? Furthermore look at the equivalent structure in the JavaFX scene graph: `Node` has a `parent` property of type `Parent` and `Parent`s have `children` of type `Node` and `Parent extends Node`.

Comment: @Chexxor BTW: i assume you're not confusing pointers and references in C++.

Comment: I assume that as well, I suppose I was just hoping that the parent and parent.parent.grid[id] worked like c++ reference variables, thus changing one changed the other implicitly... But I suppose they work like pointers, so replacing one only replaces that reference, and not the reference contents.